# Error check/handle missing values in web API call

Tags: python, json, api, parsing

I'm working on an application that retrieves weather data from a server. The server is updated every 5 minutes with weather data from various weather stations. The issue is that if there is a connection problem, or the station is unplugged there ends up being missing values. The API returns the timestamp specified, the time step between measurements, and a list of measurements.

As an example if I try to get a value every hour for a given day (24hr period) I would expect 24 values (168 for a week and 720 for 30/744 for 31days). If there's measurements missing the result is the same minus the missing values and I no way of knowing if their missing from the beginning, middle or end of the "value" key.

I have tried smaller time intervals (every value for a period - day, week, month) in order to fill the gaps between possible missing measurements but the API has request limits including a size limit that renders the smaller interval unpractical for larger requests (such as a month).

example of what is returned from the server-

```
{
 "beg_time"= 1533097205,
 "step_time": 3600,
 "value":[
  [14.7],
  [14.6],
  [14.5],
   ...
  [14.8]]
}
```

So if I end up missing measurements and end up with less than expected how would I begin to error check that? The desired results is to input the data into a file with a timestamp for each measurement. Missing values are okay but I need to know how to find them in the list. I can only relate the beg_time to the first value and each subsequent value has a time of beg_time + step_time. I need to be able to know where I'm missing a value so I can still add the timestamp into the file but leave the measurement blank.

Full example of incomplete response: only 23 values even though 24 is expected.

```
[
{
    "beg_time": 1533009600, 
    "step_time": 3600, 
    "value": [
        [
            14.6
        ], 
        [
            15.1
        ], 
        [
            14.2
        ], 
        [
            12.8
        ], 
        [
            11.6
        ], 
        [
            10.7
        ], 
        [
            11.5
        ], 
        [
            16.3
        ], 
        [
            22.3
        ], 
        [
            28.2
        ], 
        [
            29.4
        ], 
        [
            29.1
        ], 
        [
            29.3
        ], 
        [
            29.6
        ], 
        [
            30.5
        ], 
        [
            29.7
        ], 
        [
            28.9
        ], 
        [
            26.3
        ], 
        [
            24.8
        ], 
        [
            23.6
        ], 
        [
            21.2
        ], 
        [
            17.9
        ], 
        [
            15.9
        ]
    ]
}
```

]

Comment: You don't know it's missing because it's not there. Is that the question? You have to save something when you can't get the measurement. Maybe your problem is that the reading code is blocking and if the reading does not come, your code is still blocked until the next read?

Comment: When you get an error you should save something in the database that indicates that you didn't get a measurement at that time. Then you can put an empty value in the response for that step, `[[14.7], [14.6], [], [14.5], ...]`

Comment: Exactly. Like if I only get 23 values back when I expect 24 how do I know where I should be putting the empty time value in the file. The issue is just the the value at that specified time (hour increments) may or may not be missing. Its generally due to stations disconnecting (being unplugged or power outages) or wifi connection issues. Most of the weather stations are in the far northern communities of Ontario Canada, and they can have spotty power/wifi issues sometimes. I want to ensure that when they use my program it is able to account for possible missing values.

Comment: @Barmar the API and Server are not accessible and are third party

Comment: So you can't change the data that's returned? Then you're totally out of luck. The information you need is missing, there's no obvious way to reconstruct it.

Comment: Since you're not controlling what the webservice is returning, it's up to you to understand – assuming it's possible – whether something is missing. Do you have an example of an incomplete response?

Comment: @user2340612 The more I think about it I think I'm totally out of luck. The response is formatted as above in my question. When something is missing I would have less values than what I was expecting but no obvious signs like empty "[ ],".   Ill edit the question and add an example

Comment: @Seraphiim maybe the response only contains contiguous values, meaning that in the specific example only the last measure was missing. In a scenario where the i-th value is missing, you may get 2 series: 0 to (i-1) and (i+1) to 23. I guess the best way to find it out is to contact the support person/team for that webservice

Comment: @user2340612 Thats just an example. There are sometimes many more values missing. I think on Aug 10th I only have 8 values as our station in the lab was unplugged for some unknown reason so someone could use a vacuum. I think that is the best thing to do is ask the web service in question how they would approach the problem. Thank you!

Comment: @Seraphiim if you're using Netatmo API, you can try playing with `optimize` input parameter. If you set it to `false`, you'll get a response holding a different object per timestamp so that it makes it easier to find out if something is missing. Reference: https://dev.netatmo.com/en-US/resources/technical/reference/common/getmeasure

Comment: @user2340612 I am using that API and for the interval that I am using 1hour it does not separate into different objects per timestamp. I have noticed it do that for "max" but when Im asking for a range of a month the API limits me.